# Can I design an iOS app that interfaces with another?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to design an app that adds additional functionality/interfaces with the Music app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible except for jailbroken devices.

You can, however, control the Music app by using the `[MPMusicPlayerController +iPodMusicPlayer]` object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically each application that you download to an iphone exists in its own sandbox e.g. has its own file system, so it is not possible to interact with other applications. I guess it is a security thing

Answer (score 1):

About the only way is passing a URL between the applications. It is not a shared memory space but a way to launch another app with stae in the URL.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html